# Causes of difference in padding/margin between Chrome and Firefox/IE (Joomla)?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website [simkt.com](http://www.simkt.com) and just moved over to joomla 2.5 after rebuilding the base theme to match the desired look.

Unfortunately, being a novice web developer that I am, I forgot to check out how things looked in browsers other than Chrome.  The site is now live, and I quickly discovered that in Firefox/IE that the website is not quite right, and after some adjustments, that when I make adjustments to try and fix the issues, there is around a 5 pixel difference in spacing between Chrome and Firefox/IE (and I tested now in IE 7 and it was.. quite bad).

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong, and how can I go about fixing this?

Using Chrome dev, I reduced the top-padding in rt-body-bg to 0, and in the logo itself, decreased the top-margin to -30 and bottom-margin to -25 and it looks close to what I want, but has a 5 pixel gap between the logo and the menu on Firefox, and in IE the login button starts to move off in some odd direction.

I know some css/php/html but am I am still learning, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to fix. I'm looking at the site in FF and Chrome and they're nearly identical (both look fine to me). One other piece of advice: Use 'paste as plain text' to strip MS Word code when creating articles.

Comment: I will mention the MS word tip to the content writers, I'm just a web dev and did not even think to tell them that.  I need to get the menu bar and the logo looking exactly as they do in Chrome.  The owner of the website is VERY picky about pixel spacing.

Comment: Every element in the header and menu bar is identical for me in FF and Chrome, near as I can tell. What browsers (including version), and what OS are you testing on?

Comment: Windows 7, the latest Chrome, FF, and IE 9.  They are very close together.  Normally I would leave this as is, however, as I mentioned before the guy is a bit picky.  So if he notices, he will want them to match exactly between browsers.  In addition, I am looking to learn as much as I can, so I feel even if the point is moot, I can learn more about browser differences.

Answer (score 2):

Note that different browsers have different default values for the css for the different elements. A good practice when you program design with CSS is to use a reset values in the beginning of the css file. This reset is going to make sure that the unset values will be the same for every browser.

See this link for a css reset code

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Hope it helps

Comment: I am going to give this a shot when I return to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stoyan said, you should be using a CSS reset at the beginning of your CSS file.

You specifically mention margins. I've just had to resolve an issue whereby in our site margin-top was used to position items (not a great idea - blame the previous developers). In IE and Chrome it was fine but in FireFox, because it has a different top margin, it looked bad (items were 30px too low).

I didn't want to use an entire CSS reset because it might have had a knock-on effect for the entire site (fonts were all changed for example).

I used just one item to resolve it, curiously not margin-top but line-height:

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
```